# Check if a value is in an array (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

How do I check if a value is in an array in C#?

Like, I want to create an array with a list of printer names.

These will be fed to a method, which will look at each string in turn, and if the string is the same as a value in an array, do that action.

For example:

```
string[] printer = {"jupiter", "neptune", "pangea", "mercury", "sonic"};
foreach (p in printer)
{
   PrinterSetup(p);     
}
```

These are the names of the printers, they are being fed to the PrinterSetup method.

PrinterSetup will look sort of like this (some pseudocode):

```
public void PrinterSetup(printer)
{
   if (printer == "jupiter") 
   {
      Process.Start("BLAH BLAH CODE TO ADD PRINTER VIA WINDOWS EXEC");
   }
}
```

How do I format `if (printer == "jupiter")` in a way that C# can recognize?

Comment: Try giving your parameter name a type (string) and it will be fine.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as the question. Are you asking how to check if a value is in an array, or how to do string-comparison in C#? If it's the latter, you would use `printer.Equals("jupiter")`. If it's the former, use `linq` and `printer.Contains("jupiter")`

Comment: @newfurniturey Quite so ... the question is confused, the example code doesn't match the title, and thus the answers are likewise confused; why crap like this gets upvoted is beyond me. And there's no need to do `printer.Equals("jupiter")` ... The OP's code `if (printer == "jupiter")` works just fine ... as long as `printer` is declared to be a string, as Skeet notes.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

Add necessary namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then you can use linq `Contains()` method

```
string[] printer = {"jupiter", "neptune", "pangea", "mercury", "sonic"};
if(printer.Contains("jupiter"))
{
    Process.Start("BLAH BLAH CODE TO ADD PRINTER VIA WINDOWS EXEC");
}
```

Comment: @0A0D. This answer is I think straight best one as simplest/shortest and well known way to achieve same thing (`How do I check if a value is in an array in C#?`) and efficient as well. No loop no extra method. Just a namespace is extra which is not a big thing.

Comment: @Sami: Linq uses loops internally.

Comment: @0A0D Sam is probably referring to written code, not compiled instructions.  Linq uses loops and methods internally, but from the coders point of view all that is hidden and does not need to be worried about.

Comment: Right @0A0D. I meant coder/developer didnt need to right loop. Off course check from array needs a loop:)

Comment: This is certainly easy and recommendable. If you do not have access to Linq, or do not want to use Linq, you can rely on some _explicit interface implementation_ of the array. Since .NET 1.1 we have `((IList)printer).Contains("Jupiter")` which is non-generic (may box value types etc.) and works even for multi-dimensional arrays. And since .NET 2.0 we have the more magical `((IList<string>)printer).Contains("Jupiter")` which is more type-safe. The Linq approach was new in .NET 3.5.

Comment: 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<char>(IQueryable<char>, char)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<char>'

Comment: you also have the option to use it as a List<string> instead of an array.  This has a built-in contains method and it's easier to work with than arrays anyway.

Answer (score 58):

```
string[] array = { "cat", "dot", "perls" };

// Use Array.Exists in different ways.
bool a = Array.Exists(array, element => element == "perls");
bool b = Array.Exists(array, element => element == "python");
bool c = Array.Exists(array, element => element.StartsWith("d"));
bool d = Array.Exists(array, element => element.StartsWith("x"));

// Display bools.
Console.WriteLine(a); // true
Console.WriteLine(b); // false
Console.WriteLine(c); // true
Console.WriteLine(d); // false
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you use an array, it is not completely unlikely, that performance does matter. In this case, Linq is often the wrong choice.

Comment: Note that "not completely unlikely" does not imply "completely likely".  Very likely in a case like this the array size will be quite small and any performance degradation would completely undetectable. IMO the one line answer below using Linq is the clearest implementation.

Comment: @ckapilla I fail to see why you make a point of linq giving one line when that happens to be the number of lines needed for an Exists check.

Answer (score 45):

Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file. Then you can do:

```
if ((new [] {"foo", "bar", "baaz"}).Contains("bar"))
{

}
```

Comment: This is a general example - can you provide one that matches the question better?

Comment: It may be a general example, but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

```
    public static bool Contains(Array a, object val)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(a, val) != -1;
    }
```

Comment: I like this. However, it will fail if `a` is a multidimensional array (such as `new string[10, 20, 15]` for example), with an exception. It will also fail with one-dimensional arrays that are not indexed from zero (such as `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), new[] { 5, }, new[] { -2, })`, rare in C# I admit), with a possibly wrong return value. These shortcomings are easy to fix with generics: `public static bool Contains<TElement>(TElement[] a, TElement val)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(a, val) != -1;
    }`

Comment: I like this, but only because it's without Linq and it confirms that IndexOf is the only thing _left_ to use.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
string[] printer = {"jupiter", "neptune", "pangea", "mercury", "sonic"};
PrinterSetup(printer);

// redefine PrinterSetup this way:
public void PrinterSetup(string[] printer)
{
    foreach (p in printer.Where(c => c == "jupiter"))
    {
        Process.Start("BLAH BLAH CODE TO ADD PRINTER VIA WINDOWS EXEC"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Note: The question is about arrays of strings. The mentioned routines are not to be mixed with the .Contains method of single strings.

I would like to add an extending answer referring to different C# versions and because of two reasons:

- The accepted answer requires Linq which is perfectly idiomatic C# while it does not come without costs, and is not available in C# 2.0 or below. When an array is involved, performance may matter, so there are situations where you want to stay with Array methods.
- No answer directly attends to the question where it was asked also to put this in a function (As some answers are also mixing strings with arrays of strings, this is not completely unimportant).

Array.Exists() is a C#/.NET 2.0 method and needs no Linq.
Searching in arrays is O(n). For even faster access use HashSet or similar collections.

Since .NET 3.5 there also exists a generic method `Array<T>.Exists()` :

```
public void PrinterSetup(string[] printer)
{
   if (Array.Exists(printer, x => x == "jupiter"))
   {
      Process.Start("BLAH BLAH CODE TO ADD PRINTER VIA WINDOWS EXEC");
   }
}
```

You could write an own extension method (C# 3.0 and above) to add the syntactic sugar to get the same/similar ".Contains" as for strings for all arrays without including Linq:

```
// Using the generic extension method below as requested.
public void PrinterSetup(string[] printer)
{
   if (printer.ArrayContains("jupiter"))
   {
      Process.Start("BLAH BLAH CODE TO ADD PRINTER VIA WINDOWS EXEC");
   }
}

public static bool ArrayContains<T>(this T[] thisArray, T searchElement)
{
   // If you want this to find "null" values, you could change the code here
   return Array.Exists<T>(thisArray, x => x.Equals(searchElement));
}
```

In this case this `ArrayContains()` method is used and not the Contains method of Linq.

The elsewhere mentioned .Contains methods refer to `List<T>.Contains` (since C# 2.0) or `ArrayList.Contains` (since C# 1.1), but not to arrays itself directly.

Comment: I suggest to change name to ArrayContains() to avoid confusion with the Linq Contains()

Comment: I´ve done this, although there are also arguments against: It is the basic idea of polymorphism to use the same name for different data types, Especially with a Linq-setting in mind. Using different names is not polymorph.
But readibility and avoiding misunderstandings shall win, I think, so, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Not very clear what your issue is, but it sounds like you want something like this:

```
    List<string> printer = new List<string>( new [] { "jupiter", "neptune", "pangea", "mercury", "sonic" } );

    if( printer.Exists( p => p.Equals( "jupiter" ) ) )
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing something in your method:

```
public void PrinterSetup(string printer)
{
   if (printer == "jupiter") 
   {
      Process.Start("BLAH BLAH CODE TO ADD PRINTER VIA WINDOWS EXEC"");
   }
}
```

Just add `string` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`HashSet<T>` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) for the sake of lookup performance:

> This method is an O(1) operation.
>
> — [`HashSet<T>.Contains` Method (T), MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
class PrinterInstaller
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> PrinterNames = new HashSet<string>
        {
            "jupiter", "neptune", "pangea", "mercury", "sonic"
        };

    public void Setup(string printerName)
    {
        if (!PrinterNames.Contains(printerName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown printer name", "printerName");
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to use a HashSet on a collection as small as printers and in this case it might not even be faster due to HashSet overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I searched now over 2h to find a nicely way **how to find duplicates** in a list and **how to remove them**. Here is the simplest answer:

```
//Copy the string array with the filtered data of the analytics db into an list
// a list should be easier to use
List<string> list_filtered_data = new List<string>(analytics_db_filtered_data);

// Get distinct elements and convert into a list again.
List<string> distinct = list_filtered_data.Distinct().ToList();
```

The Output will look like this:
Duplicated Elements will be removed in the new list called distinct!