# C# Linq - If input is not equal to any of the string[]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, if-statement

I have an error code here, because I can't check if string is equal to string[].

```
public void SetCh1Probe(string input)
{
    string[] option= {"1:1", "1:10", "1:100"}

    //I wanna check if input is equal to any of the string array
    if (input != option.Any(x => x == option))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");
    }

    else
    {
        //Proceed with other stuffs
    }
}
```

I will have tons of methods like this, each with different `string[] options`. I really want to have a neat template that I can use for the rest of the methods. Can anybody help?

Comment: I believe `setting.Any` should be `option.Any` If I understand your question correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a value is in an array (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257458/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-c)

Comment: Yea, that was a typo. Anyway, sorry for the duplicate. I can't believe I couldn't find that thread before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your condition from

```
if (input != option.Any(x => x == option))
```

To

```
if (!option.Any(x => x == input))
```

Or another alternative

```
if (option.All(x => x != input))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
    public void SetCh1Probe(string input)
    {
        string[] setting = { "1:1", "1:10", "1:100" };

        //I wanna check if input is equal to any of the string array
        if (!setting.Contains(input))
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");
        }

        else
        {
            //Proceed with other stuffs
        }
    }
```