# C# Use an array to blacklist what someone has input

Tags: c#, arrays

```
        string name;
        string[] Blacklist;
        Blacklist = new string[10];

        Blacklist[1] = "Example1";
        Blacklist[2] = "Example2";
        Blacklist[3] = "Example3";
        Blacklist[4] = "Example4";
        Blacklist[5] = "Example5";
        Blacklist[6] = "Example6";
        Blacklist[7] = "Example7";
        Blacklist[8] = "Example8";
        Blacklist[9] = "Example9";
        Blacklist[10] = "Example10";

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        if (name = Blacklist[]) 
                            ^^
```

This is where I'm stuck 
I want to make the name blacklisted to all the values in the array
So I can use this to filter all the names that are inappropriate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a value is in an array (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257458/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Blacklist.Any(x => x.Equals(name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, your variable is not named per the convention, i.e. lower camel case.  It should be `blacklist`.

Comment: Another option would be List<string> blacklist and use Contains(string) but this is the answer to the question ... using array

Answer (score 1):

Hi maybe you want to use contains.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Blacklist.lenght(); i++)
 if(Blacklist[i].Contains(name) )
```

you can also convert all for lower and then compare

Comment: I'll keep it in mind, still getting used to the basics. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This is the long hand version of rory.ap's answer. I recommend in knowing what this does exactly before trying to understand what rory.ap's answer does.

Comment: @Chad one minor difference: this is case sensitive where mine is case insensitive