# How to compare a string value to an element of an string array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

In the following program i want to check (via defencing programming) if the user input(named day)
matches with one of the elements of the string array (named weekdays).

By now ive done the following.can anyone help(for a better solution)?thank you.

....

```
string[] weekdays = new string[7] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

      Console.WriteLine("Give me a day: ");
        String day= Console.ReadLine();


         for (i=0; i< weekdays.Length; i++)
        {
            if (weekdays[i] == day)
            {

                break;
            }
            else if (weekdays[i] != day && i==6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again");
                day = Console.ReadLine();
                i = -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/q/13257458/6299857

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) function:

```
using System.Linq;
...

string[] weekdays = new string[7] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

Console.WriteLine("Give me a day: ");
String day= Console.ReadLine();

//No need to iterate over array and check day exists in array or not.
//You can use .Contains() method as well.
if(weekdays.Any(x => x == day))   
     break;
else
{
      Console.WriteLine("Try again");
      day = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you want it in loop then you can use `while(<condition>)` or `for` loop as per your requirement

[From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

> Linq Any() method: Determines whether any element of a sequence exists
>   or satisfies a condition.

---

You can use below logic which will do same operation without any linq function and simplified solution:

```
//Week days array
string[] weekdays = new string[7] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

//While infinity loop to execute inner code till incorrect day enters like "hey" 
while(true)
{
   //Read first input from user
   Console.WriteLine("Give me a day: ");
   string day= Console.ReadLine();

   //flag to check user entered correct value or not
   bool isAvailable = false;
   foreach(var wday in weekdays)
   { 
      //If entered day is correct then set flag and exit from foreach loop 
      if(wday == day)
      {
         isAvailable = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   //Check flag and if entered value is wrong then read user input again.
   if(isAvailable)
      break;
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Try again");
      day = Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the advice.however (if you can of course) can you explain to me how it works with the while loop or for (without the .Any function) i would aprreciate that.Thank you again !

Comment: What you want to do it with for loop or while loop, as per your question you were looking for a better solution for checking that the `day` exists in any array or not. which this answers satisfies. but I did not understand your else loop. Do you want to check `day` again if user enters other than `weekdays`?

Comment: there are couple of alternatives for `.Any()` function(which I already mentioned in my answer) like `.Contains()`, `.Exists()` and so on. but what exactly you are trying to do? Do you want to perform this logic without `Linq` methods?

Comment: the else loop is for the case that the user input would have some other value than the elements like "hey"

Comment: @NavyAlsk, Check my latest updated

Comment: i saw your answer and i really appreciate your help.youre right about this kind of solution but ive learned that defencive programming(because my teacher told me to solve it using defensive programming) requires the do..while loop or the while loop.but thanks.a lot.

Comment: Now its your homework to convert this program to use `do..while` or `while` loop