# How to check if a string is contained in an array of strings?

Tags: c#

I'm about a week into learning C# with 0 prior coding knowledge. Can someone please tell me why this wouldn't work?

```
string[] afirmatives = {"Yes", "yes", "YES", "Yeah", "yeah", "YEAH", 
                        "Yep", "yep", "YEP", "Yup", "yup", "YUP", "Y", "y" };

/*string afirmatives = "Yes";*/

Console.Write("Are you a Human? ");
string humanAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
string answer = (humanAnswer = afirmatives) ? 
   "That sounds like something a robot would say." 
   : "Invalid Input";
        
Console.WriteLine(answer);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I know I can get it to work with just a single string value but what do I need to do differently to use the multiple?

Do I have to make multiple if else lines?

Thank you!

**Edit**

Xareth helped me get to the answer.  I needed to add a "Contains" something or other.  This is the new and operational code.

```
string[] afirmatives = {"Yes", "yes", "YES", "Yeah", "yeah", "YEAH", 
            "Yep", "yep", "YEP", "Yup", "yup", "YUP", "Y", "y" };
        Console.Write("Are you a Human? ");
        string humanAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
        string answer = humanAnswer = afirmatives.Contains(humanAnswer)
            ? "That's something a robot would say."
            : "Invalid Input";
        
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is in an array (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257458/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-c)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Whilst statements like _"I'm about a week into learning C# with 0 prior coding knowledge."_ may or may not be suitable in a post, it's generally better to not to include it into the posts **Title**.  The title should be a _short description of the problem_ written almost the same way as you would when using _search engines_ (though on SO it should be an _independent clause_).  This will help others help you today and in the future.  Good luck

Comment: A single equal sign is an assignment operator not an equality operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
using System.Linq;  
string[] afirmatives = {"Yes", "yes", "YES", "Yeah", "yeah", "YEAH",
                        "Yep", "yep", "YEP", "Yup", "yup", "YUP", "Y", "y" };

/*string afirmatives = "Yes";*/

Console.Write("Are you a Human? ");
string humanAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
string answer = (afirmatives.Contains(humanAnswer)) ?
"That sounds like something a robot would say."
: "Invalid Input";

Console.WriteLine(answer);
Console.ReadLine();
```

notice `using System.Linq;` at the top

The reason `humanAnswer = afirmatives` doesnt work is because `=` is an [assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator). By using this you're trying to make `humanAnswer` take the value from `afirmatives`.

To compare strings you should use an [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators). So in the case where `string afirmatives = "Yes";` the following would be valid `humanAnswer == afirmatives`.

However, you're comparing `humanAnswer` to an array and so using Linq is an easy way to test if an array or list contains a value

Comment: Rather than using all of the case differences, why not simply String.ToUpper() the input and make all of these string upper case?  Your sample would fail on "yeP" or "YeP".. for example.  Otherwise, I like your sample code.

Comment: Or `bool found = Array.Exists(affirmatives, a => a.Equals(humanAnswer, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)); string answer = found ? "" : "";`

Comment: _"The reason humanAnswer = afirmatives doesnt work is because"_ - suffice to say I think we can ignore that as OP posted code with a [compilation error](<iframe width="100%" height="475" src="https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/zJqHGW" frameborder="0"></iframe>).  C# isn't c/c++.  +1 regardless

Comment: Wow. Thank you!  I replaced what I had with the "afirmatives.contains" part and it cleared up that error.  When I added the "using System.Linq" it gave me another separate error that I started trying to understand.  I started to erase it and go back to my original code but noticed that after I took out "using System.Linq" all my errors went away and the code worked as expected.

Thank you!!!  

I'm not sure exactly why it works now and it didn't before but I'm sure I'll learn soon enough.

Comment: yeh, sorry. `using System.Linq;` has to go right at the top, outside the class or program and typically up near `using System;`

Comment: Now that you say that I can see that makes more sense than where I put it and it already has one up there.  Either way it works now so again, thank you.  I don't think my learning has covered "Contains" yet.  I'll stick to smaller projects.