# Break line where one of the char is match

Tags: c#

I have a long string, and this string must break at the 15th character or earlier.

In the example string

> This must break right here

the 15th character is the letter 'k', so check if it is one of `{ ' ' , '.', ',' }`. If it is, break the line in this position, otherwise check the preceding character until it can break. In the example it can break at character 10.

My code is only working if I can break on only one character in the equals clause:

```
char break = ' ';
```

If I use an array of possible characters (`char[] canBreak = { ' ' , '.', ',' };`), it doesn't work.

Here is my code that doesn't work, I think the problem is in the Equals:

```
char[] canBreak = { ' ' , '.', ',' };
char break = ' ';

while (!fullMsg[breakValue].Equals(canBreak))
{
    breakValue = breakValue - 1;
}
```

If I use only one `char` instead of `char[]` it works:

```
char[] canBreak = { ' ' , '.', ',' };
char break = ' ';

while (!fullMsg[breakValue].Equals(break))
{
    breakValue = breakValue - 1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One character is not equal to an array of characters. So the condition in while will always return false. That's why it is not working.

Comment: You should use following condition in while. `while(Array.IndexOf(canBreak, fulMsg[breakValue]) >=0)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867377/checking-if-a-string-array-contains-a-value-and-if-so-getting-its-position

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is in an array (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257458/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `canBreak.Contains(fullMsg[breakValue])` to check if your char is one of `' ' , '.', ','`.

```
char[] canBreak = { ' ' , '.', ',' };

while (!canBreak.Contains(fullMsg[breakValue]))
{
    breakValue = breakValue - 1;
}
```

This uses [`Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_) from `System.Linq`.