# How do I check if value exists in array

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, try-catch

I'm new to programming and am currently working on a calculator program.

I want the program to give an error message if none of the listed operators are being mentioned in the user input.

Here's my code:

```cs
int Number = 0;
string operation = "0";
string[] func = { "+", "-", "*", "/", ":", "x^2", "%", "cos", "bin" };

 while (true)
 {
    try
    {
        Number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose your operation: \n \n + \n - \n * \n : \n x^2 \n % \n cos \n bin");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
        operation = Console.ReadLine();

        if (operation != func)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Error! Please try again:");
    }
}
```

But, it says cannot use the `!=` operator with a string and an array. *(Compiler Error CS0019)*

How can I check if a user input (operator) is in an array, so I can throw a new exception?

Comment: Is your question actually "how to check if an element exists in an array?"? If it is, your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257458/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-c). If not, can you explain what you mean more precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (!func.contains(operation)) 
{ 
    throw new Exception("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check if the operation is **included** in `func` array.
but the line `operation != func` checks if operation is not **equal** to array.

You need to loop the array instead and check if there is an element in the array that is equal to operation:

```cs
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < func.Length; i++)
    if (operation == func[i])
          found = true;
if (found == false)  // operation is not found
    throw new Exeption();
```